# How to rename multiple files in Google Drive at once using a syntax?

Tags: google-apps-script

Does there exist a Google Apps Script that lets the user rename multiple files at once using a specific syntax?
Like "delete part X from the filename Y of all files in folder Z" or "change strings like "one", "two", "three", ... to numbers like "1", "2", "3", ...".

For example, in the folder "Stories", all filenames may be be like "Book 1 Chapter 1 The Beginning", "Book 1 Chapter 2 A New Chapter", and I could want to remove the string "Book 1 ", so that all filenames will look like: "Chapter 1 The Beginning", "Chapter 2 A New Chapter".

I'd like the Script to have a Graphical User Interface with input fields, buttons, lists, etcetera so that I can manage all [the names of] my files using just one Script.

Comment: This could be useful indeed and I didn't see it yet... but I'm sure that you're going to want it to do "replace" in names or renumbering with prefix and so forth... That would be absolutely feasible with Google Apps Script and I would be very pleased to have it ! So all I can say is "go ahead" and share your work. You have UiApp or HTML Service for the Ui and DriveApp for all the files renaming process. The other possibility is to use the Mac/PC synch app and use a renaming tool on your computer files... too easy ! I hope you'll choose the first solution ;-)

Comment: It's almost crazy that for such seemingly simple tasks like renaming files an average user like me has to make an entire Google Apps Script as a Web App that isn't prone to errors. Maybe the OP was a little bit misleading (I have now edited the question), but let's make it clear that I am not a (good) programmer, but I am merely asking for an already existing error-free solution. And if that solution doesn't exist yet, I'll have to accept my improperly organized file- and foldernames. Thanks for your informative comment anyway.

Comment: The solution using Drive synch on Mac works nicely for me but it is far from impossible that I don't try to make it myself in Apps-Script :-)  If I do I'll update here (I'll try not to forget...) Maybe someone else might be exited by this idea?  Who knows?

Comment: It would be excellent if you'd make (at least a part of) such a Google Apps Script-as-a-Web App.

Comment: If you sync your Drive with a Windows PC, you can then use something like the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Ask and thy shall receive! Allow me to introduce [Bulk Renamer for Google Drive™](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz5f5BJ6OVf8w23Ntva2bC0ltUw9TieX5FPylpLoVaNUMWFRuaY/exec) - a web app written in Google Apps Script (coming to a Chrome Web Store near you real soon).

Comment: @azawaza would be nice if the script only asked for permission for scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes thou it probably means using drive advanced service.

Comment: This question looks like a "give me the code" kind of question.

Comment: Download all the files from that directory to your PC.  Open Adobe Bridge on your computer.   Batch rename through Bridge (it has some killer options).  Then re-upload.  Done.

Comment: If you need help with Google App Script you can send your problem to mail.raghvendra.kumar@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the [Bulk Renamer for Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-renamer-for-google-d/peboiggabkeljjdnbelmhbpnmonomngo) app
2. If you have that Google Drive folder synced to your computer, you can use [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) on your local machine's copy of that folder.

BRU has more options/flexibility than Bulk Renamer, including regex support. Bulk Renamer's main advantage is that it works with Google Drive directly in the browser, without needing to wait for Google Drive to sync from your local machine.

Comment: Linking to the GitHub repo for BRU: https://github.com/azadisaryev/BulkRenamerForGoogleDrive

Answer (score 0):

You can use this google chrome extension to rename multiple files.

[Bulk Renamer for Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-renamer-for-google-d/peboiggabkeljjdnbelmhbpnmonomngo)

Go to their advanced rename option and you can easily do it.